# why this ValueError: Could not save to PNG for display in python3.0 is showing?

Tags: python, transparency

I am a complete newbie to this coding and programming and I need your help guys.

```
blue = Image.open('blue_color.png')
blue.putalpha(128)
blue
```

output

```
ValueError: Could not save to PNG for display
```

Answer (score 0):

The runtime is probably broken the runtime due to a library conflict during installation.
The same case occurred in cv2_imshow(), which was working well. 
In my case, running [Restart runtime] cleared the bug.

- menu / Runtime / [Restart runtime]

Answer (score 0):

If not too late, the file in that collection is not valid, just save a new blue png from google or something to the same place and crop it, it shouldn't give the same error with the replacement file.